# How to remove empty space in always visible searchview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, searchview, fragment-backstack

I am trying to display a search view as soon as I open my app and give it focus, and prevent the back arrow `<-`, because pressing back causes :

1. firstly the keyboard to close
2. then the search view to collapse, clearing the query and also the displayed results resulting in an empty fragment --- **instead of this I'd rather it skip this and go straight to 3, exiting the activity**
3. then the third back is needed to exit the activity

I only wanted max 2 back actions to exit the activity. So I did the following in my search fragment:

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.search, menu);

  var searchMenu = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);
  searchMenu.ExpandActionView();
  _searchView = searchMenu.ActionView.JavaCast<SearchView>();
  _searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(false); // <-- I added this
  _searchView.RequestFocus();
  _searchView.QueryTextChange += async (s, e) => {
    await PerformSearch(e.NewText);
  };

  var searchText = _searchView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.search_src_text);
  searchText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
  searchText.Hint = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.search_hint);

  base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:text="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always" <-- I took out collapseActionView from here
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Now as soon as my activity launches and switches to the fragment I get this blank space on the left, how can I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the defaul blank space in Android **OptionsMenu**, you can not modify it. If your **OptionsMenu** only contain a **SearchView** item, there is a method to reduce its length. You could not use **OptionsMenu**, and add **SearchView** into **Toolbar** directly. You know **OptionsMenu** also is created based on **Toolbar**.

Therefore, you could find the xml code of **Toolbar** and add `SearchView` as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In **Activiy**, also add focus function code:

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView searchView = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView);
searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(false);
searchView.RequestFocus();
searchView.QueryTextChange += (s, e) =>
{
    //await PerformSearch(e.NewText);
    Console.WriteLine(e.NewText);
};

var searchText = searchView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.search_src_text);
searchText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
searchText.Hint = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.search_hint);
```

The effect:

[image]